# SYSTIME causes IDL program error

Tags: gis, raster, idl-programming-language

I have been assigned an IDL coding assignment for a class. This language is new to me but I have been programming awhile so this error perplexes me. I cannot use the systime() function to add the date and time to an outputted filename.

Not shown in code: created mosaicRaster containing a mosaicked raster image of 4 geotiffs.

```
outputRaster = filepath + 'outputFile' + SYSTIME() + '.tif'
mosaicRaster.Export, outputRaster, 'TIFF'
```

The program completes with no errors.. just does not output my file. If I change it to:

```
outputRaster = filepath + 'outputFile.tif'
```

the program runs fine.

I have tried to put STRING() around SYSTIME(), and also around outputRaster.

The funny/weird/miserable thing is that SYSTIME(/SECONDS) runs fine. It is only when SYSTIME does not have a parameter it gives a problem.

Additionally, these statements work:

```
time = SYSTIME(/SECONDS)

PRINT, SYSTIME()
```

This does not work (Program exits without outputting my raster):

```
time = SYSTIME()
```

Again, there are no errors. I have scoured help documentation and nothing is to be found. My professor has looked at my code and says his looks exactly the same (he runs a mac, I am using a windows VM in the lab). The file is just not outputted. You may ask why do I need to append the filename with the current date... its a requirement on this final project.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colon's are not valid on Windows and spaces are usually a pain to deal with. Easiest fix is to use `IDL_VALIDNAME` to fix the date up:

```
IDL> print, idl_validname(systime(), /convert_all)
Thu_Feb__8_11_01_05_2018
```

Answer (score 1):

SYSTIME() produces a string with characters that are illegal in a Windows path (namely, colon).

```
c:\>mkdir "Mon Jan 18 20:14:07 2038"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

c:\>mkdir "Mon Jan 18 20-14-07 2038"
(no error)
```

SYSTIME(/SECONDS) produces a string with numerals and a dot, which is legal.
https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/systime.html